# Django generic UpdateView returns 404 error: "No user found matching the query" when using pk

Tags: python, django

I am creating a Django web app and want to use the generic UpdateView by passing in a user's primary key. It works for the DetailView, but not the UpdateView.

I've tried specifying the template_name, changing the order of paths in my urls.py file. I haven't tried using a slug yet, but I know I should be able to use a pk.

I am using the built-in User model from django.contrib.auth below for my profile.

views.py:

```
class Profile(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'

class ProfileUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name']
    template_name = 'accounts/profile_update_form.html'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth

# Create your models here.

class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',default='media/block-m.png')
    skills = models.TextField()
    major = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    grad_year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    clubs = models.TextField() #make FK to Clubs
    opt_in = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My urls.py is what frustrates me the most. The address http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/5/ works fine, but http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/5/edit/ returns a 404 error "No user found matching the query". So I know that the pk=5 exists, but doesn't work for my url ending in /edit/.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'),name='login'),
    path('logout',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name='logout'),
    path('signup/',views.SignUp,name='signup'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/',views.Profile.as_view(),name='profile'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/edit/',views.ProfileUpdate.as_view(),name='profile_update'),
]
```

profile_update_form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form layout='inline' %}
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign Up">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It looks that you used a `User` model instead of a `Profile` (?) model?

Comment: Show your working ProfileUpdate view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem will you please take a look at: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72391987/using-urls-path-with-slug-returns-page-not-found-404-no-profile-found-matching) Please

Answer (score 1):

That's because user.pk is not the same as primary key for the same users userprofile, if you check their respectable tables in database you will see the difference, yes it is confusing at first simplest solution I did is using signals:

```
 def profile_creation_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs) :

    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(pk=instance.id, user=instance)

post_save.connect(profile_creation_signal, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### It should work!

`path('<username>/', ProfileView.as_view(), name="public_profile"),`

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = "pages/public_profile.html"
    context_object_name = "profile"
    slug_field = "username"
    slug_url_kwarg = "username"
```

You can replace -username- with unique fields