# Using urls path with slug returns Page not found (404) No profile found matching the query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to create user Profile for my django project, I'm using [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) to allow user to edit Profile model when they want to create profile for their account but it return an error every time I click on create profile url in the profile template.

the error message:

```
Page not found (404)
    No profile found matching the query
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000//6/edit
    Raised by:  answer.views.EditProfileView
```

Profile Template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        {% for profile in profiles %}
        <div class="col">
            <a href="{{profile.website}}">{{profile.website}}</a>
            <a href="{{profile.twitter}}">{{profile.website}}</a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="{% url 'editProfile' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="avatars/")
    stories = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
```

my urls:

```
path('editprofile/<slug:slug>/edit', views.EditProfileView.as_view(), name='editProfile'),
```

my views:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def profile(request, pk):
    profiles = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'questions':questions, 'profiles':profiles}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)

class EditProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['profile_image', 'stories', 'website', 'twitter', 'location']
    template_name = 'edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(Creator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my index template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <a href="{% url 'question' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Ask Question</a>
                <a href="{% url 'notification' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Notifications
                    {% if unread_notifications %}
                    <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{unread_notifications}}</span>
                    {% endif %}
                </a>
                <a href="{% url 'FeedBack' %}" class="btn btn-primary">FeedBack</a>
                <a href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</a>
                <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Log Out</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ur path is editprofile/<slug:slug>/edit.  Why you send {% url 'editProfile' user.id %}

Comment: secondly u cant use slugify(self.user)  u should use slugify(self.user['field'])

Comment: `UpdateView` doesn't have a `save` method... what are you trying to do there??

Comment: @ElvinJafarov because I want to redirected user to the **edit_profile** template.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly fix

```
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user.field) #field is what you want to slugfiy 
        super(Creator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

secondly

You are sending **ID** but url requires slug

```
  #old
  <a href="{% url 'editProfile' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</a>

  #should be
  <a href="{% url 'editProfile' user.slug_field %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</a>
```

Comment: Your answer throws an error in the profile template **Reverse for 'editProfile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editprofile/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/edit\\Z']** and it highlight this url: **<a href="{% url 'editProfile' user.slug_field %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</a>**

Comment: @DeeAdamu It is because `user` takes data from `User` table and in which you don't have any field name `slug_field`, it is only a reproductible example the Answerer has shown, not exact field. Again see my solution which perfectly matches your table `Profile` with given `slug` field which is passed in the template file or your profile.html.

Comment: I copy this url: **  <a href="{% url 'editProfile' user.slug_field %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</a>
** and pass it into my **profile template**

Comment: and its returns this error in the profile template **Reverse for 'editProfile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['editprofile/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/edit\\Z']**

Comment: @DeeAdamu Yes, the error you are getting because simply passing `user.slug_field` makes no sense, since it is not any field in `User` model, but it is in your `Profile` model, hereby Answerer means that you should pass some user's slug field which your `EditProfileView` want, its way of telling, not exact fields. That's why I passed `profile.slug` since it is coming from the `profile` as an instance from `get_object_or_404`.

Comment: but you are not passing **profile.slug** in the url you are passing **user.slug** check your code you will see

Comment: @DeeAdamu I am releasing that you haven't look at my answer and code correctly and patiently, see I am passing `profile.slug` in `profile.html` in the view `EditProfileView` which has the name `editProfile`  and I have also included the `Note` of that, see it correctly, and again look at the whole answer it will resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have made `user` a `OneToOneField` in your `Profile` model, that means you should not use `filter()` in `profile` view, you should use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for getting single user's profile, as it has `OneToOneRelation`.

Try this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
@login_required(login_url='login')
def profile(request, pk):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,user=request.user)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'questions':questions, 'profile':profile}
    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)

class EditProfileView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['profile_image', 'stories', 'website', 'twitter', 'location']
    template_name = 'edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

profile.html:

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            {% comment %} {% for profile in profiles %} {% endcomment %}
            <div class="col">
                <a href="{{profile.website}}">{{profile.website}}</a>
                <a href="{{profile.twitter}}">{{profile.website}}</a>
            </div>
            {% comment %} {% endfor %} {% endcomment %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="{% url 'editProfile' profile.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> `Note:` I have passed `profile.slug` since the `EditProfileView` also requires slug to come in route.

> `Note:` You should not run loop while displaying data with single object.

index.html (success template):

```html
<body>
<h3>Profile updated successfully.</h3>
</body>
```

edit_profile.html

```html
<body>
    <h2>You can edit your profile </h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
</body>
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile-updated/', views.index, name='index'),
    path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('editprofile/<slug:slug>/edit/',
         views.EditProfileView.as_view(), name='editProfile')
]
```

That will successfully update your profile.

Comment: Your answer returns **Page not found (404)
No Profile matches the given query.** my profile has  **pk** see: **path('profile/<int:pk>/', views.profile, name='profile'),** and you are not passing id in the **profile** view

Comment: It is because you have logged through superuser, check it, kindly logged through that user which exist in your `Profile` model with all its fields. I haven't shared urls.py because I think you can understand without it, i have passed it.

Comment: Your answer should return **Page not found (404)
No Profile matches the given query.** because in my index template I pass this url to redirected me to profile page  **<a href="{% url 'profile' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Profile</a>** the problem is the url I have pass in the index.html

Comment: I've  debugged it, it is working perfectly. You question is about slugs returns 404.

Comment: what **url** did you pass in your index.html that will redirected you to the profile page ?

Comment: And how you are telling  about your view which has name `profile`, your question is about I want to edit profile, but it throws the error, neither you shared your template file from which you are passing `user.id` to `profile` view, we are not magician.

Comment: @DeeAdamu I haven't seen your index.html, I have made it because to redirect the message for debugging and it works perfectly.

Comment: @DeeAdamu What problem do you exactly facing now?

Comment: I have updated my question. the problem I'm facing is that when i click on my **profile** url it throws an error:  **Page not found (404)
No Profile matches the given query.**